# Reading columnar data -- better approach than var1=$(cat|awk); var2=$(cat|awk), etc?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

What's a more elegant way of declaring multiple variables from awk outputs? I have two files that are auto-generated. The files can have as many as three lines. Here's a sample of the variable declarations that I did so far:

```
$ cat OUTF1.tmp
        25          16      8.33 VERY GOOD
        12          17        25 OK
$ cat OUTF2.tmp
        30          60      15.38 VERY GOOD
```

---

```
TMP1="OUTF1.tmp"
TMP2="OUTF2.tmp"
```

---

```
MATH_101=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==1{print $1}' )
ENGLISH_101=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==1{print $2}' )
SCIENCE_101=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==1{print $3}' )
GRADE_101=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==1{print $4}' )

MATH_102=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==2{print $1}' )
ENGLISH_102=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==2{print $2}' )
SCIENCE102=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==2{printf $3}' )
GRADE102=$(cat $TMP1 | awk 'NR==2{print $4}' )

MATH_201=$(cat $TMP2 | awk 'NR==1{print $1}' )
ENGLISH_201=$(cat $TMP2 | awk 'NR==1{print $2}' )
SCIENCE_201=$(cat $TMP2 | awk 'NR==1{printf $3}' )
GRADE_201=$(cat $TMP2 | awk 'NR==1{print $4}' )
```

and so on...

The variable contents should then be:

- MATH_101=25
- MATH_102=12
- ENGLISH_101=16
- ENGLISH_102=17
- etc.

Are there better ways than hard-coding these variables?

Comment: Why in the world are you using `awk` for this at all?

Comment: BTW, all-caps variables are actually bad form. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; application-defined variables should be in lowercase, which guarantees that they can't conflict.

Comment: Also, the file seem to have 4 lines

Comment: As an aside -- `cat file | somecommand` is considerably less efficient than `somecommand <file` (or its equivalent `<file somecommand`, if you prefer reading left-to-write). The former starts `cat` as a separate process, and gives `somecommand` a FIFO (a non-seekable, non-rewindable, read-once pipeline) on the output from `cat`; the latter just gives `somecommand` a real file handle, meaning it can jump around in the file, reread parts, and doesn't need to depend on a separate process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Does it? I didn't think STDIN was seekable.

Comment: @123, not if it's coming from a terminal, but if's redirected from a file, it's same as any other file handle.

Comment: Afungus, what are you *doing* with these variables, once you've collected them? The best way to collect this data will depend heavily on what your goal is.

Comment: `GRADE_101` will just be `VERY`, not `VERY GOOD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be literally just as easy to read straight from your input file to your shell script the correct way as to read from input->awk->shell... so the sensible answer is to do the former.

---

First, to go the simple but straightforward approach:

```
{
  read MATH_101 ENGLISH_101 SCIENCE_101 GRADE_101
  read MATH_102 ENGLISH_102 SCIENCE_102 GRADE_102
  read MATH_201 ENGLISH_201 SCIENCE_201 GRADE_201
} <infile
```

Getting a bit fancier:

```
for level in 101 102 201; do
  read {MATH,ENGLISH,SCIENCE,GRADE}_"$level"
done <infile
```

Since you have two separate input files, if you want to concatenate them into a single stream, consider replacing `<infile` with `< <(cat file1 file2)`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I'm still curious how the GRADE_101 got "VERY GOOD" instead of just "VERY"?

Comment: @Afungus The last read variable captures the remainder of the line. For example if you just had `read MATH_101`, `$MATH_101` would contain the entire line.